# How can I extract data by parsing sub branch of MongoDB between two dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, mongodb, dataframe

I am trying to extract data from MongoDB by using python code.
Mongo DB format looks like in this format:

```
DB1 - subDB1, subDB2....
DB2 - subDB1, subDB2...
DB3 - subDB1, subDB2....
```

What I want is connect to `DB1` and loop through its subDB and extract data from certain Dates.

This is my code:

```
mongodb = MongoHandler() # this is a class which connects to my Mongo client

collection = mongodb.getCollection('DB1', 'subDB1')

from_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)
dateAt = yesterday.strftime('%y%m%d')
query = {
    'number': 1234
    'dateAt': {
        '$gte': from_date,
        '$lte': dateAt 
    }
}
projection = {'_id':False,
                'datetimeAt':True,
                'branch': 2,
                "branch.total" :  True, 
}
```

This one gives me value from only one `subDB1`. I tried to write only `('DB1', 'subDB')` but it didn't work.

So how can I loop through main DB and its all sub DB and extract data `from to now` by using python code?

Can I get some help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your databases names and collections names in a variable, and loop through them.
For example

```
collection_names = [
    ('DB1', 'subDB1'),
    ('DB1', 'subDB2'),
    ('DB2', 'subDB1'),
]
for db_name, collection_names in collection_names:
    collection = mongodb.getCollection(db_name, collection_names)
```

---

If you are using `pymongo` you have method to retrieve all your databases names or all the collections names in your database.

```
# Get all databases    
client.list_database_names()

# Get all collections in a specific database
db.list_collection_names()
```